# Changing the map from SateliteView to TrafficView or viceversa using dialog

Tags: android

I want to change the map from sateliteView to TrafficView by selecting the dialog as mentioned in image

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it as following.

check out this

```
 //set Satellite view
m_mapView.setSatellite(true);
m_mapView.setTraffic(false);          


//set trafic view
m_mapView.setSatellite(false);
m_mapView.setTraffic(true);
```